# RxJs marble testing : Assertion fail log hard to understand

Tags: testing, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-marbles

I have this Rxjs testing code. It fail deliberately, because i want to show you the failing log. Which i found hard to understand, or at least i cannot read it fluently.

Someone can explain me what means : `$[i].frame = i' to equals i''` ?

```
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';

describe('Rxjs Testing', () => {

  let s: TestScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    s = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });

  it('should not work', () => {
    s.run(m => {
      const source = s.createColdObservable('-x-y-z|');
      const expected = '-x-y-z|'; // correct expected value is '---x-y-z|'

      const destination = source.pipe(delay(2));
      m.expectObservable(destination).toBe(expected);
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: `frame` is an internal representation of time in `TestScheduler`. I think you can think of it as every async action creates a new frame and increments `TestScheduler`'s internal counter. I think every `-` in marble diagrams represented 10 frames but maybe this has changed (maybe to 1?). So the error tells you that emission happened in different times then you expected.

Comment: I think that `-` is equals to 1, which explained by the delay(2) and the expectations logs (there's always a diffrence of 2). By  << every async action creates a new frame >> you mean (x, y, z) in the test ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help you better understand what is going on with the output, let's first try to follow statements from the console. There is a link that points at where the error has happened. It's at 10th line of code which is this line:

```
expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
```

Setting breakpoint to this line and running the test in debug mode reveals `actual` and `expected` objects.

`actual` values are (represented in JSON format):

```
[
  {
    "frame": 3,
    "notification": {"kind": "N", "value": "x", "hasValue": true}
  },
  {
    "frame": 5,
    "notification": {"kind": "N", "value": "y", "hasValue": true}
  },
  {
    "frame": 7,
    "notification": {"kind": "N", "value": "z", "hasValue": true}
  },
  {
    "frame": 8,
    "notification": {"kind": "C", "hasValue": false}
  }
]
```

And the `expected`:

```
[
  {
    "frame": 1,
    "notification": {"kind": "N", "value": "x", "hasValue": true}
  },
  {
    "frame": 3,
    "notification": {"kind": "N", "value": "y", "hasValue": true}
  },
  {
    "frame": 5,
    "notification": {"kind": "N", "value": "z", "hasValue": true}
  },
  {
    "frame": 6,
    "notification": {"kind": "C", "hasValue": false}
  }
]
```

Comparing the two arrays, you can see that `frame` properties are different for each object of the same index. This weird output comes from Jasmine's [toEqual](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#toEqual) function, so let's try to understand it based on the values from above. This line from the console

```
Expected $[0].frame = 3 to equal 1.
```

means that expected value of 1 is not 1, but is actually 3. This part `$[0].frame = 3` suggests what the actual value is, and this `to equal 1` is what you as developer think it should be. I.e. `expected[0].frame` (which is 1) is not equal to `actual[0].frame` (which is 3). And so on, `expected[1].frame` is not equal to `actual[1].frame`...

Now, you may wonder why do you even get such values for `actual` and `expected`. This is explained much more in detail on the [official docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md). When you create cold observable with this marble diagram `-x-y-z|` and `delay` it with `2` units, it becomes `---x-y-z|` which is then transformed to something comparable - an `actual` array. The first three `-` signs indicate three empty, non-emitting frames. They are at the positions 0, 1 and 2. They do not have representations in any of the two arrays.

Then comes the first real value `x`. It is represented as the first object in `actual` array (`actual[0]`). `x` is at position 3 thus the `frame` property has the same value. `notification` property has some meta data like the `value` of the emitted item. You can conclude values for `y` and `z` the same way.

Side note: when using `run()` method, frames become values of 1, 2, 3, etc. instead of 10, 20, 30 when not using `run()`, for [legacy reasons](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md#marble-syntax).

Comment: Tks for such detail

Comment: I would recommend using [rx-sandbox](https://github.com/kwonoj/rx-sandbox) , I wrote an article about it: https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/how-to-easily-write-and-debug-rxjs-marble-tests/

Comment: @Mokkapps I just saw your comment, i'll check thank you